# Find missing numbers in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, reduce

I am writing this code to find missing numbers from a given array. This code works fine when i pass 1,4 as arguments but 5,10 it fails to push new items to the array. What am I doing wrong?

```js
 function sumAll(arr) {
   max = Math.max(...arr);
   min = Math.min(...arr);
   toFill = max - min;
   for (i = min + 1; i <= toFill; i++) {
     arr.push(i);
   }
   return arr.sort().reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);

 }

 sumAll([5, 10]);
```

Comment: I think i immediately found my problem. if my min is equal to my 'toFill' my for loop will not run... makes sense now. Will look into it further and post an update.

Comment: just delete the question, if you found your own solution.

Comment: I didnt find the solution, i found a problem that may help find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say i <= min+toFill

```
function sumAll(arr) {
   max = Math.max(...arr);
   min = Math.min(...arr);
   toFill = max - min;
   for (i = min + 1; i <= min+toFill; i++) { console.log(i);
     arr.push(i);
   }
   return arr.sort().reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr);

 }
```

Comment: I had to get rid of += in my for loop. 
for(i = min +1; i < min+toFill; i++)